# Как использовать дизайнер форм при разработке нативных программ на C++ в Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Само название Visual Studio как бы намекает, что эта среда предназначена для визуальной разработки. Я это понимаю так, что внешний вид приложения делается в дизайнере. Но в реальности полноценный дизайнер там есть только для разработки под .NET, а для разработки нативных приложений есть только диалоги в ресурсах.

Вот я отдизайнил некий диалог в ресурсах. Что с ним дальше делать? Каким образом его дальше можно использовать? И можно ли таким образом отдизайнить главное окно приложения, или же только вызываемые в нём диалоги, а в главном можно только обработать сообщения создания и отрисовки?

Comment: Для разработки UI на С++ студия из коробки предлагает только UWP XAML. Можно еще воспользоваться (по факту устаревшим) MFC.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [официальный урок](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-basic-windows-10-app-in-cpp) от Microsoft по XAML / C++.

Comment: А это не CLR? Это вроде бы не то, что диалоги в реусрсах.